# Wake screen by touching screen (not pressing power button)?

Tags: lock-screens, lineageos

Is there a way to wake/unlock my screen by touching the screen itself and not by pressing power the button?

In other words, I want the screen's backlight to turn off after a certain amount of time, and then turn on when I touch the screen.

Comment: It needs kernel level support. A feature called double tap to wake up does exactly that, except it needs double tap (to prevent screen waking up on accidental single taps). I don't think single tap to wake is a feature that would be demanded by users so you probably have to find the kernel patch that works for double tap, tweak it for single tap, rebuild the kernel with your patch and see if it works. And, double tap to unlock feature also exist with a particular implementation on XDA.

Comment: @Firelord Yeah, it seems the "double tap to wake" feature depends on one's hardware.